# Rally Analytics 2.0 - Error 413: Request Entity Too Large

Tags: sdk, analytics, rally

I have been writing an app which uses the lookback tool to get the total number of points a project had within it on a certain date. The request to pull this information looks as follows:

```
getPointsOn: function(date, iOIDs, callback) {
    var params    = {};
    params.find   = '{ Iteration: {$in: [' + iOIDs + ']}, PlanEstimate: { $gt: 0 }, __At: "' + date.toISOString() + '" }';
    params.fields = '[ "PlanEstimate", "Project" ]';

    Ext.Ajax.cors = true;
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: App.qURL,
        method: 'GET',
        params: params,
        withCredentials: true,
        success: function(response) {
            var points = {};
            Ext.Array.each(Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText).Results, function(US) {
                if (points[US.Project] == undefined) points[US.Project] = 0;
                points[US.Project] += US.PlanEstimate;
            });
            callback(points);
        },
        failure: function() {
            console.log('Ajax Failed');
            callback({});
        }
    });
}
```

It returns an object with Project/Points pairs and works perfectly when 1-2 iteration ObjectIDs are passed to it. The problem is when I start requesting larger data sets. I have been getting the "Request Entity Too Large" error. I assume this is a problem with the request itself although I'm not sure how it could be "too large". What is the likely cause of this error?

Thanks!

Comment: I have targeted the issue: when making the Ajax request it is trying to attach a cookie I have saved, which it doesn't actually need. Is there a way I can disable this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Large state elements, such as the values selected from a picker, should be stored with a Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider instance, rather than a Ext.state.CookieProvider. Assuming that the cookie does not need to be sent to fulfill the query request.

Answer (score 1):

You can do an Ext.util.Cookies.clear(cookieName) to remove a cookie.  Generally the maximum request size for ALM is 8k so a large pref cookie combined with a large number of iteration oids could hit that limit.

Also, there is a more fully supported way to access the Lookback API in SDK 2.0p4.
http://developer.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p4/doc/#!/api/Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore

```
Ext.create('Rally.data.lookback.SnapshotStore', {
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, data, success) {
            //process data
        }
    },
    fetch: ['PlanEstimate', 'Project'],
    filters: [
        {
            property: 'Iteration',
            operator: 'in',
            value: iOIDS //an array
        },
        {
            property: 'PlanEstimate',
            operator: '>',
            value: 0
        },
        {
            property: '__At',
            value: date.toISOString()
        },
    ],
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Comment: Kyle, this looks great but I'm getting an error when trying to pull the data: "Ext.Error: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String". Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Also, is there a way to just not send the cookie with the request? I would like to keep it saved for later use, but it is not needed for the query itself.